# Scheduling round-robin double-headers across two locations

Tags: algorithm

**Summary**: Does a valid schedule exist that meets the constraints below? If so, what is a general algorithm for generating it?

I am scheduling a league of 14 teams. Each week every team plays a double-header (two games). There are 7 fields available. Every team should play both games each night. In 7 weeks, no team should play the same opponent a second time. (The last week is only a single header, since it only takes 13 rounds of games for each team to see the others.)

So far so good; I can [generate this schedule](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54715.html). With unique letters for each team, one such schedule looks like this:

```
Week 1: AN BM CL DK EJ | FI GH
        AM LN BK CJ DI | EH FG

Week 2: AL KM JN BI CH | DG EF
        AK JL IM HN BG | CF DE

Week 3: AJ IK HL GM FN | BE CD
        AI HJ GK FL EM | DN BC

Week 4: AH GI FJ EK DL | CM BN
        AG FH EI DJ CK | BL MN

Week 5: AF EG DH CI BJ | KN LM
        AE DF CG BH IN | JM KL

Week 6: AD CE BF GN HM | IL JK
        AC BD EN FM GL | HK IJ

Week 7: AB CN DM EL FK | GJ HI
```

But there is a wrinkle, shown by the bar above. 5 fields are at one location, 2 fields are at a second location. It is strongly undesirable to have a team play the first game at one location and the second game at the other location.

- *In the above, during Week 1 teams `G` and `H` and `F` get to stay at the second location, but teams `E` and `I` have to switch locations between games.*

Is it possible to have a schedule where location 2 always has four teams who stay there for both games? Or is there a limitation that makes this impossible (along with the other constraints above)?

If there is such a schedule, is there a general algorithm to generate it?

---

For this to work, the games at location 2 need to look like:

```
UX VY 
UY VX
```

The schedule that I generated above does not have any such pairs of games, due to the round-robin algorithm I used. It seems to me like it should be possible, but a few hundred thousand passes with a simulated annealing algorithm massaging that schedule and I can't seem to get below a certain number of required location transfers.

Comment: Dear anonymous close-voter: if you know that this question has too many possible answers, I'd appreciate you dropping a hint in the right direction. Or is it that you simply do not know whether or not such an answer exists? :/

Comment: I don't know the answer to your overall question, but there is one other possibility for the games at location 2: `UX VY; UV XY`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I think that is only swapping the labels `Y` and `V`.

Comment: You're right -- I forgot that order doesn't matter, so `VY = YV`.

Comment: If you look at the 1st two columns, the number of teams in those two columns is always 5. If you can reduce this to 4, then you are good because you can shift those to columns to the different location. I'm not sure whether it is possible, but it is a line of thought you can consider.